# Calculate the inverse matrix of a diagonal blockwise matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix-inverse

I have a large matrix `M` like this

```
M=[A1, Z,  Z,  Z,  Z,  Z ; 
   Z,  A2, Z,  Z,  Z,  Z ; 
   Z,  Z,  A3, Z,  Z,  Z ; 
   Z,  Z,  Z,  A4, Z,  Z ; 
   Z,  Z,  Z,  Z,  A5, Z ; 
   Z,  Z,  Z,  Z,  Z,  A6];
```

`A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6` are 4×4 real symmetric matrices, and `Z=zeros(4,4)`.

How to calculate the inverse of `M` when there are millions of `A` in the matrix `A1,A2,A3,..., An`?

I know that I can simplify the inverse matrix to

```
invM=[B1, Z,  Z,  Z,  Z,  Z 
      Z,  B2, Z,  Z,  Z,  Z 
      Z,  Z,  B3, Z,  Z,  Z 
      Z,  Z,  Z,  B4, Z,  Z 
      Z,  Z,  Z,  Z,  B5, Z 
      Z,  Z,  Z,  Z,  Z,  B6];
```

`B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6` are inverse matrices of `A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6`. But when there are many many `B`, how to do batch processing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have the image processing toolbox you should have a look at the `blockproc` function

Comment: How are your `A` matrices actually stored? Is `M` stored as a sparse matrix or do you just store the `A` blocks? Are all of the `A` matrices unique?

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I wouldn't bother about the inverse. Chances are you don't need the inverses at all, but rather, you need the *products*

```
x(n) = inv(A(n))*b(n)
```

where `b` is the solution vector in the equation `Ax = b`.

Here's why that is important:

```
clc

N = 4;    % Size of each A
m = 300;  % Amount of matrices

% Create sparse, block diagonal matrix, and a solution vector
C = cellfun(@(~)rand(4), cell(m,1), 'UniformOutput', false);
A = sparse(blkdiag(C{:}));
b = randn(m*N,1);


% Block processing: use inv()
tic
for ii = 1:1e3
    for jj = 1:m
        inds = (1:4) + 4*(jj-1);
        inv(A(inds,inds)) * b(inds); %#ok<MINV>
    end    
end
toc

% Block processing: use mldivide()
tic
for ii = 1:1e3
    for jj = 1:m
        inds = (1:4) + 4*(jj-1);
        A(inds,inds) \ b(inds);
    end
end
toc

% All in one go: use inv()
tic
for ii = 1:1e3
    inv(A)*b;
end
toc

% All in one go: use mldivide()
tic
for ii = 1:1e3
    A\b;
end
toc
```

Results:

```
Elapsed time is 4.740024 seconds.  % Block processing, with inv()
Elapsed time is 3.587495 seconds.  % Block processing, with mldivide()
Elapsed time is 69.482007 seconds. % All at once, with inv()
Elapsed time is 0.319414 seconds.  % All at once, with mldivide()
```

Now, my PC is a little different than most PCs out there, so you might want to re-do this test. But the ratios will be roughly the same -- computing explicit inverses simply takes a lot more time than computing the product `x = inv(A)*b`.

If you run out of memory when using `mldivide`, you shouldn't loop over all the individual matrices, but rather split the problem up in larger chunks. Something like this:

```
chunkSize = N*100;
x = zeros(size(A,1),1);
for ii = 1:N*m/chunkSize
    inds = (1:chunkSize) + chunkSize*(ii-1);
    x(inds) = A(inds,inds) \ b(inds);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The inverse of a diagonal matrix is only B = 1/A.

Here the proof : http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Diagonal_Matrix

Comment: But this is a block-diagonal. Each of those `A` is 4x4. The OP actually states this solution in the question. What it is asking is how to calculate so many inverses efficiently.

Comment: my matrix is diagonal blockwise, not diagonal

Comment: What's the problem with a loop?

Comment: I have millions of A. It takes too long.

Comment: You can have a look to section [Block Tridiagonal matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix) maybe that can give you idea. Else you need an LU Decomposition or something like that.